# how to convert instance of an object to byte and byte to object

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm implementing an application that will need to send an instantiating object to a tcp socket client, doing this in java alone is extremely simple, however doing this in dart is being impossible, I'm not talking about json, serializing an object in json is useless, what I'm trying to do is take an instantiated dart class and send it to a dart server where the server will create the instance of that object, as I said in java this is extremely simple, in java using Serializable, we convert the object into byte and send it through network, on the other side we take the bytes of the objects and cast them to the object, please, I'm not talking about using dart's jsondecod or anything like that, that's not it, I'm talking about bytes of an object instance.

Has anyone tried to do something like this? or at least tried to convert a dart object instance to byte or even tried to save a dart object instance in the directory? when I talk about an object I'm not talking about a map but the instance itself.

I am being very repetitive because what seems to me is that when we use it for serialization, the people of dart only know json, it even seems to me that there is nothing else besides json, in the end if someone can help me I will be very grateful

I tried to find some method or library that helps me to get the object instantiated and convert it into bytes.

```
void main(List<String> arguments) async {
   //simple test object
   MessageDto messageDto = MessageDto(
   msg: 'essa é a menssagem',
   action: 'action',
   method: 'method',
);

 //I need to convert the instance to bytes
 List<int> buffer = object.fromBytes(messageDto);
 send(buffer);
}
```

the code above is just an idea of what I need

Comment: There's really no generic API for an object to be converted to and from a universal serialization.  Each class must define for themselves what will be used.  JSON is a popular format, but doesn't take care of anything other than a handful of primitive types.

Comment: When Flutter uses method channels to talk to native, it uses a message codec that converts most Dart types to and from a binary representation. You could consider reusing that existing framework.

Comment: I've already tried to update the binary but I wasn't successful, I'll try again, thanks for the tip